# How can I print the schema id from kafka-console-consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I want to print the schema id of a received avro message from `kafka-console-consumer`.

I have tried the following command from inside confluent platform ([docker-based](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one)):

```bash
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic_name \
--property print.schema.ids=true --property \
 schema.registry.url="http://schema-registry:8081" \
--value-deserializer io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:515)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:505)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:112)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:132)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.<init>(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.java:295)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.<init>(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.java:58)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:48)
        at kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter.getDeserializerProperty(ConsoleConsumer.scala:609)
        at kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter.$anonfun$configure$22(ConsoleConsumer.scala:515)
        at kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter.configure(ConsoleConsumer.scala:615)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsoleConsumer.scala:325)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:51)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

What am I missing. Is there any other flag that I should instead use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried to do the same as you today and came upon:

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer \
  --topic topic_name  \
  --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
  --bootstrap-server kafka-broker:9092 \
  --property print.key=true \
  --property print.schema.ids=true \
  --property key.separator="-" \
  --partition 0 \
  --offset 2423843 \
  --max-messages 3
```

this CLI command exists in the `confluentinc/cp-schema-registry` docker image.

Here some related information:

- https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/kafka-console-consumer-producer-avro/kafka.html
- https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/901

Comment: The problem was that I was using the [docker version](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.5.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml) and expected to find `kafka-avro-console-consumer` inside the broker's container. I did not find it, thus I tried to fall-back to the available `kafka-console-consumer` command. When I connected to the registry's container I found the command `kafka-avro-console-consumer`.

Comment: @MarinosAn That command (with all its properties) comes with the schema registry bin directory, yes